# Why is my Travis-CI build still failing?

Tags: android, git, travis-ci

For the last four builds, all of them have failed but I can not figure out why. It is giving me an error, but when I check the code in my IDE (Android Studio), I have no errors, but just warnings. Is it interpreting the warnings as errors? Here is the error given by the log:

```
Lint found 1 errors and 6 warnings
:mobile:lint FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
```

Comment: "Lint" errors probably mean something along the lines of "code style" errors. And yes, it's probably interpreting warnings as errors, and [so should you](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/94754/how-do-i-convince-my-teammates-that-we-should-not-ignore-compiler-warnings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your gradle is configured to fail the build if your code does not match LINT rules.

You can do any of the following attempts:

1. Fix everything in your code that LINT complains about (Most recommended)
2. Silence the lint by setting quiet mode or `abortOnError` to false:

```
lintOptions {
        quiet true
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
    }
```

3. Disable all gradle tasks that start with `lint` at the beginning of your tasks

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

4. Run the build task with `-x lint` argument like: `gradlew assemble -x lint`